# Setting the default page and adding tab click events

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app and my problem consists on two factors:

1. I need the login page as startup page. If I set `CurrentItem="{x:Reference homeTab}` (or `loginTab`), the bottom `TabBar` no longer appears on any page. Currently it's hidden only on login and even if I set `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"` on the home page it won't appear. Also, removing the `CurrentItem` line will make it visible again.
2. How can I set click events on the `TabBar`? I need to have some logic behind it and not only navigate to a specific route.

Below is my shell xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlusErp.Wms.Mobile.Views"
       xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:PlusErp.Wms.Mobile.Resources"
       Title="PlusErp.Wms.Mobile"
       x:Class="PlusErp.Wms.Mobile.AppShell"
       CurrentItem="{x:Reference homeTab}"
       >

    <!--
        The overall app visual hierarchy is defined here, along with navigation.
    
        https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/
    -->

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
    
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Back}" Icon="arrow_left.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent x:Name="loginTab" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Logout}" Icon="logout.png" Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
        <ShellContent x:Name="homeTab" Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Home}" Icon="home.png" Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.InfoStock}" Icon="search.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Forward}" Icon="arrow_right.png" Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Comment: Here is a similar issue that maybe can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181503/shell-bottom-tab-bar-hide-if-set-to-true-settabbar.html

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT unfortunately this is not working (also mentioned by the other person in the link you've shared). I've tried setting it in both pages (on appearing / dissappearing)